# C: why are none of the monsters eating the player?

Tags: c, linked-list, comparison, coordinates, nodes

I have a program that reads from a text file the map (obstacles, monsters, treasure, spawnpoint of player) and a player can then move via WASD keys to the treasure, with monsters M and obstacles # in the way.

Some maps have 3 or more monsters.

Why does the monster 'obj' not eat the player when they're at the same coordinate?

```
        if (obj->x == player->x && obj->y == player->y) {
```

seems to not work for co-ordinate comparison

```
void move_monsters() {
    list_node *monster = monster_position;
    list_node *treasure = treasure_position;
    game_object *obj;
    game_object *obj2;
    while (monster) {
        unsigned possibilities[4][2];
        int position_count = 0;

        obj = monster->object;
        obj2 = treasure->object;

        if (isMovable(obj, obj->x + 1, obj->y)) {
            possibilities[position_count][0] = obj->x + 1;
            possibilities[position_count][1] = obj->y;
            position_count++;
        }
        if (isMovable(obj, obj->x - 1, obj->y)) {
            possibilities[position_count][0] = obj->x - 1;
            possibilities[position_count][1] = obj->y;
            position_count++;
        }
        if (isMovable(obj, obj->x, obj->y + 1)) {
            possibilities[position_count][0] = obj->x;
            possibilities[position_count][1] = obj->y + 1;
            position_count++;
        }
        if (isMovable(obj, obj->x, obj->y - 1)) {
            possibilities[position_count][0] = obj->x;
            possibilities[position_count][1] = obj->y - 1;
            position_count++;
        }
        // If the monster (obj) eats the treasure (obj2), the game is over.
        if (obj->x == obj2->x && obj->y == obj2->y) {
            printf("GAME OVER\n");
            free_memory();
            printf(KNRM);
            exit(0);
        }

        // If the monster (obj) eats the player, the game is over.
        if (obj->x == player->x && obj->y == player->y) {
            printf("GAME OVER\n");
            free_memory();
            printf(KNRM);
            exit(0);
        }

        // Do nothing if no moves are available.
        if (position_count) {
            int target = rand() % position_count;
            move_object(monster->object, possibilities[target][0], possibilities[target][1]);
        }
        monster = monster->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `obj->x == player->x && obj->y == player->y` is every actually met? What is `position_count`? I'd look at it in a debugger or add a few `printf` statements and find out what it is doing. There isn't any way of anyone testing further without an MCVE. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you can move the player to the monster's coordinate and they'll be in the same coordinate, but it will just show M. If I move `if (obj->x == obj2->x && obj->y == obj2->y) {` to another method, only 1 monster will eat the player and the others will not.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and find out the values of obj->x, obj->y, player->x, player->y.

Comment: @CarolineRudolph I see what you want to do, I just can't tell from what you have posted whether `obj->x == player->x && obj->y == player->y` ever occurs so that the *monster* eats the *player*. There just isn't any way that anyone can determine what `obj->x` or `player->x` is within your code. If the test tests true, then the code block should execute. I don't see anything wrong there.

Comment: Either `x` or `y` (or both) of `obj` vs. `player` are not the same, regardless of what your display is showing.  Are you certain that `obj` and `player` have their coordinates updated correctly when moving?

Answer (score 0):

These monsters are rather stupid: they do not move to eat the treasure or the player when either one is within reach, just one step away. A collision between the player and the any of the monsters is just coincidental and the player can move out of danger before the monster can eat it at the next iteration.

If this never happens, I suspect the player never runs into a monster willingly and the `isMovable()` function considers the player's position as unavailable, preventing the monster from moving in to eat the player.

Comment: isMovable is enabled for monsters running into players